# Set default scroll options in vim

Tags: vim

Does vim have possibility to set scroll options globally and for all time?
I want to set scroll option in vim equal to 10 , to navigate by Ctrl+U and Ctrl+D by 10 lines always. I have done it from command line, but it works only until I switch to another tab or open another file.

If I write in .vimrc.local

```
set scroll=10
```

It seems doesn't work.

EDIT: I use spf13 build. Please, don't refer me to the issue tracker of repository, because people answer there very slowly or don't answer at all.

Additional information:

```
 "verbose set scroll output
 scroll=29
    Last set from ~/.vimrc.local
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `autocmd BufEnter * :set scroll=10`

Comment: According to [the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scroll%27) it should work. Did you reload your .vimrc? (by restarting vim or running `:source ~/.vimrc`)

Comment: add the scroll setting in your `.vimrc`, start vim, pls report the output of `:verbose set scroll`

Comment: Hi, Kent. Thanks for comment. I have updated my question, check it please. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: Have the same using neovim. Did you figure how to fix that?

Comment: @sudobangbang I can confirm that `set scroll=10` doesn't work but yours works! Thank you! `NVIM v0.5.1 LuaJIT 2.0.5`

Answer (score 1):

Try a remap if nothing works :

```
nnoremap <C-u> 10k
nnoremap <C-d> 10j
```